# CMake error when building OpenCV - CMakeLists not match

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi, opencv3.0

I attempted to build OpenCV 3.1.0 on my Raspberry Pi 2B. Unfortunately, when I ran:

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \ -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \ -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \ -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF  /home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0

I received a following error:

> CMake Error: The source "/home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.

I want to use OpenCV with C++ and Code::Bocks, which I have already installed.
I can't find any solution on internet, so I'd be very gratefull if someone helps me. I am using Raspbian Jezzy.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, I hope you do run CMake **outside** your sources, in a separate directory. Not doing that is really not recommended

To understand the error message you have to know a little bit on how CMake works.

Basically, when you run

```
cd /path/to/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

CMake generates a cache in the build dir (It's a simple file named `CMakeCache.txt`). This file contains some information like:

- The path to the sources /path/to/opencv
- The path to the build dir /path/to/opencv/build
- The CMake Generator used (Ninja, Unix Makefiles ...)

If you ever re-run CMake and change one of these values, (by re-running cmake with different arguments, setting an other generotor or moving files), CMake will complain with this kind of message.

A good solution is then to delete the CMakeCache, or even the whole build dir to be safe.

Comment: As you say, the solition was to delete build folder. Thanks for help :)

Comment: I am using the CMake gui in windows. In addition to deleting the build directory I also (or only?) needed to activate "File > Delete Cache" in the GUI.

Comment: I ran into this when a CMakeCache.txt file was somehow placed right at the roof of my c: directory.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is you have used two version of cmake to generate the Makefile.

```
cd /path/to/opencv
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

that will be work fine.

- Installing OpenCV 2.4.9 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
  http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/