# How to configure a complex project with CMake Tools plugin?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code

I am trying to configure vscode to develop llvm/mlir project with the CMake Tools plugin.
The project is big and requires passing this configuration to the command-line:

```
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
mkdir llvm-project/build
cd llvm-project/build
cmake -G Ninja ../llvm \
   -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=mlir \
   -DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
   -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;NVPTX;AMDGPU" \
   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
   -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON \
   -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DLLVM_ENABLE_LLD=ON \
   -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=python3
```

I tried to add this information into `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/llvm",
    "cmake.configureArgs": [
        "-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=mlir",
        "-DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON",
        "-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD='X86;NVPTX;AMDGPU'",
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
        "-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON",
        "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang",
        "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++",
        "-DLLVM_ENABLE_LLD=ON",
        "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=python3",
    ]
}
```

But the configuration is not successful and it appears that my arguments were not detected.

```
[main] Configuring folder: llvm-project 
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/clang-10 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/clang++-10 -H${HOME}/Development/mlir/llvm-project/mlir -B${HOME}/Development/mlir/llvm-project/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
[cmake]   contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
[cmake]   code such as
[cmake] 
[cmake]     project(ProjectName)
[cmake] 
[cmake]   near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
[cmake] 
[cmake]   CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
[cmake]   line.
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /bin/clang-10
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /bin/clang-10 -- works
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/clang++-10
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/clang++-10 -- works
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:26 (if):
[cmake]   Policy CMP0057 is not set: Support new IN_LIST if() operator.  Run "cmake
[cmake]   --help-policy CMP0057" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
[cmake]   set the policy and suppress this warning.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   IN_LIST will be interpreted as an operator when the policy is set to NEW.
[cmake]   Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (if):
[cmake]   if given arguments:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "NVPTX" "IN_LIST" "LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Unknown arguments specified
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as
[cmake] 
[cmake]     cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
[cmake] 
[cmake]   should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
[cmake]   if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
[cmake]   information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "${HOME}/Development/mlir/llvm-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How can I transform the configuration line into something that the CMake Tools plugin can understand?

EDIT: Adjusted the error message

EDIT2:

Modifying `.vscode/settings.json` to use `cmake.configureSettings` did not solve the problem:

```
{
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/llvm",
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS" : "mlir",
        "LLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES" : "ON",
        "LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD" : "\"X86;NVPTX;AMDGPU\"",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE" : "Release",
        "LLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS" : "ON",
        "CMAKE_C_COMPILER" : "clang",
        "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER" : "clang++",
        "LLVM_ENABLE_LLD" : "ON",
        "PYTHON_EXECUTABLE" : "python3",
    }
}
```

Comment: This error message has been asked about *several* times on this site, have you tried any of the potential solutions associated with those? e.g. one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784700/cmake-error-when-building-opencv-cmakelists-not-match)

Comment: Just found this info "

Warning

Always prefer to use cmake.configureSettings or CMake Variants. Never pass -D arguments using this setting. " at this link (https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#conf-cmake-buildenvironment). But i am still unclear on how to use this function.

Comment: @squareskittles sorry I have pasted the incorrect error message on my first submission. I have updated the error message to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem / possible bug.

It appears that vscode and CMake Tools plugin caches some files and **even if you delete the build folder** (that holds the CMakeCache.txt) the project does not use new configurations parameters modified on `.vscode/settings.json`.

So, to get my project working.

1. I added this information to `.vscode/seetings.json`:

```
{
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/llvm",
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS" : "mlir",
        "LLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES" : "ON",
        "LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD" : "X86;NVPTX;AMDGPU",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE" : "Release",
        "LLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS" : "ON",
        "CMAKE_C_COMPILER" : "clang",
        "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER" : "clang++",
        "LLVM_ENABLE_LLD" : "ON",
        "PYTHON_EXECUTABLE" : "python3",
    }
}
```

2. **Closed vscode**
3. Deleted the build folder
4. Opened vscode
5. Answered yes to: "Would you like to configure project 'llvm-project'?"

And the configuration was successful.

Now you can select your targets using vscode.

Unfortunately it appears that every time vscode is opened the CMake plugin triggers a new configuration, but it is probably better to address this issue in another question/forum.

Answer (score 0):

In `.vscode/seetings.json`, use an **array syntax** to specify multiple options instead. For example,

```json
{
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/llvm",
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        //...
        "LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD" : ["X86", "NVPTX", "AMDGPU"],
        //...
    }
}
```